# How to extract particular data from a array of objects and post that to firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object

I have an array of objects, by which i need loop through the array and extract particular data from the every objects.

Here is my array of objects, when i console logged :

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 21, timestamp: 1550707200000, dateString: "2019-02-21"}
1: {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 22, timestamp: 1550793600000, dateString: "2019-02-22"}
2: {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 23, timestamp: 1550880000000, dateString: "2019-02-23"}
3: {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 28, timestamp: 1551312000000, dateString: "2019-02-28"}
4: {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 27, timestamp: 1551225600000, dateString: "2019-02-27"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I need to extract "dateString" from this array of objects, and i need to save this to firebase as a arrays. Example ["2019-02-21", "2019-02-22"...]. So how to do the extraction ? And , we can save data to firebase using set, update etc for an single data. How to save this extracted array to firebase ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Extracting the strings to  different array is a very basic mapping operation. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is to help fix your code, not do all the work and research for you. There are many many examples on this site and all over the web for the first step. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Sorry for this kind of questions, @charlietfl ! I was using map function in the console log , that's why I dint get the out put. With the below said , answer I tried that and it's working ! Will change the way I ask questions from next onwards ! Thanks for the words

Comment: OK. That's why I provided links so you can learn to use this site better. note that showing code attempts and basic research are expected. Not trying to be a hard ass, rather trying to help you learn how to get the most from the site and what is expected of users asking questions

Comment: Definitely , understood.  Thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to "extract" the data. About firebase you'll have to look at the docs your self. Just google it.

```js
const data = [
  {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 21, timestamp: 1550707200000, dateString: "2019-02-21"},
  {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 22, timestamp: 1550793600000, dateString: "2019-02-22"},
  {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 23, timestamp: 1550880000000, dateString: "2019-02-23"},
  {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 28, timestamp: 1551312000000, dateString: "2019-02-28"},
  {year: 2019, month: 2, day: 27, timestamp: 1551225600000, dateString: "2019-02-27"}
];

const dates = data.map(d => d.dateString);

console.log(dates);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I used map in console log that's why it wasn't working ! Then tried as u said , thanks for the help !